# configuration Fail2ban with Proftpd on Puppet

Tags: puppet, proftpd, fail2ban

- I want to change the variable "enabled" in jail.conf of Fail2ban according to the status of Proftpd on the agent machine.
- Ex: If on the agent machine, Proftpd is running, "enable = true" (Fail2ban will monitor Proftpd)
  If Proftpd is stopped, "enable = false" (Fail2ban won't monitor Proftpd)
- My init.pp file :

  class fail2ban {
      package { "fail2ban":
              ensure => "installed",
      }

  ```
  service { "fail2ban":
          ensure => "running",
          enable => "true",
          require => Package["fail2ban"],
  }
  $path = "/var/run/proftpd.pid"
  $status = inline_template("<% if File.exist?(@path) -%>true<% else -%>false<%end -%>")
  file { "jail.conf":
          path    => '/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf',
      ensure  => file,
      require => Package['fail2ban'],
      content => template("fail2ban/jail.conf.erb"),
  notify  => Service['fail2ban'],
  }
  ```

My template `jail.conf.erb` file:

```
[proftpd]
enabled  = <%= $status %>
port     = ftp,ftp-data,ftps,ftps-data
filter   = proftpd
logpath  = /var/log/proftpd/proftpd.log
maxretry = 5
```

The problem is that my "enabled" result is according to the check on Puppet Master, not the agent machine, while I need to do the check on the agent machine.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Sorry, I have a mistake in "jail.conf.erb" file.
"enabled = <%= @status %>"  not "$status". The result is always according to the check on Puppet master machine.